# Does a ResultSet load all data into memory or only when requested?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I have a .jsp page where I have a GUI table that displays records from an Oracle database. This table allows typical pagination behaviour, such as "FIRST", "NEXT", "PREVIOUS" and "LAST". The records are obtained from a Java ResultSet object that is returned from executing a SQL statement.

This ResultSet might be very big, so my question is:

If I have a ResultSet containing one million records but my table only displays the data from the first ten records in the ResultSet, is the data only fetched when I start requesting record data or does all of the data get loaded into memory entirely once the ResultSet is returned from executing a SQL statement?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The Java ResultSet is a pointer (or cursor) to the results in the database. The ResultSet loads records in blocks from the database. So to answer your question, the data is only fetched when you request it but in blocks.

If you need to control how many rows are fetched at once by the driver, you can use the [setFetchSize(int rows)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#setFetchSize(int)) method on the ResultSet. This will allow you to control how big the blocks it retrieves at once.

Comment: Does MySql driver (mysql-connector-j) support such "intelligent" behavior?

Comment: @Roman The JDBC API does not indicate that it is an optional method. I would assume all implementations including mysql would support this.

Comment: If "all implementation supports" then how JDBC-ODBC bridge can do this for MS Access? Access doesn't support "limits" or something similar, does it?

Comment: The fetch size is basically a "suggestion" to the driver how many records to fetch at a given time and it is up to the driver whether to use the suggested size or to ignore it. I imagine most well designed drivers use it. jTDS (for SQL Server) uses it.

Comment: Nice answer +1.  Could we get a documentation reference for this behavior?

Comment: @ChrisDail How the ResultSet loads records in blocks from the database? What I am thinking that sql query will be executed only once, then how it loads in blocks??

Answer (score 12):

The JDBC spec does not specify whether the data is streamed or if it is loaded into memory. Oracle streams by default. MySQL does not. To get MySQL to stream the resultset, you need to set the following on the Statement:

```
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(
        sql,
        ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
        ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    pstmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

Comment: I wonder if there are any updates to this for MYSQL 8

Answer (score 1):

While the JDBC spec does not specify whether or not the all data in the result set would get fetched, any well-written driver won't do that.

That said, a scrollable result set might be more what you have in mind:
(link redacted, it pointed to a spyware page)

You may also consider a disconnected row set, that's stored in the session (depending on how scalable your site needs to be):
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/sql/RowSet.html

Comment: FYI: The exampledepot.com throws up a "harddrive needs to be fragmented" warning kinda message.

Answer (score 1):

The best idea is make a sub query and display 100 or 1000 rows at a time/in single page. And managing the connection by connection pooling.

To make a sub query you can use Row count in oracle and Limit in MY SQL.

Answer (score 0):

lets say we have a table that contains 500 records in it

```
PreparedStatement stm=con.prepareStatement("select * from table");
stm.setFetchSize(100);// now each 100 records are loaded together from the database into the memory,
// and since we have 500 5 server round trips will occur.
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();
rs.setFetchSize (50);//overrides the fetch size provided in the statements,
//and the next trip to the database will fetch the records based on the new fetch size
```