# Total Number of Row Resultset getRow Method

Tags: java, jdbc

Read the Following Code:

```
public class selectTable {

public static ResultSet rSet;
public static int total=0;
public static ResultSet onLoad_Opetations(Connection Conn, int rownum,String sql)
{
int rowNum=rownum;
int totalrec=0;
try
{
   Conn=ConnectionODBC.getConnection();
   Statement stmt = Conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);        
    String sqlStmt = sql;        
    rSet = stmt.executeQuery(sqlStmt);
    total = rSet.getRow();        
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("Total Number of Records="+totalrec);
    return rSet;
    }

}
```

The folowing code dos't show actual total:

```
total = rSet.getRow();
```

my jTable display 4 record in jTable but total = 0; when I evaluate through debug, it shows:

```
total=(int)0;
```

rather than total=(int)4
And if I use

```
rSet=last(); above from the code  total = rSet.getRow();
```

then total shows accurate value = 4 but rSet return nothing. then jTable is empty.
Update me!

Comment: because `totalrec` never been used ?

Answer (score 26):

BalusC's answer is right! but I have to mention according to the user instance variable such as:

```
rSet.last(); 
total = rSet.getRow();
```

and then which you are missing

```
rSet.beforeFirst();
```

the remaining code is same you will get your desire result.

Comment: You should mention that that `rSet.last()` can throw if `rSet` type is `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#last())

Answer (score 16):

You need to call [`ResultSet#beforeFirst()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#beforeFirst%28%29) to put the cursor back to before the first row before you return the `ResultSet` object. This way the user will be able to use `next()` the usual way.

```
resultSet.last();
rows = resultSet.getRow();
resultSet.beforeFirst();
return resultSet;
```

However, you have bigger problems with the code given as far. It's leaking DB resources and it is also not a proper OOP approach. Lookup the DAO pattern. Ultimately you'd like to end up as

```
public List<Operations> list() throws SQLException {
    // Declare Connection, Statement, ResultSet, List<Operation>.

    try {
        // Use Connection, Statement, ResultSet.

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            // Add new Operation to list.
        }
    } finally {
        // Close ResultSet, Statement, Connection.
    }

    return list;
}
```

This way the caller has just to use `List#size()` to know about the number of records.

Answer (score 3):

The [getRow()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getRow%28%29) method retrieves the current row number, not the number of rows. So before starting to iterate over the `ResultSet`, `getRow()` returns 0.

To get the actual number of rows returned after executing your query, there is no *free* method: you are supposed to iterate over it.

Yet, if you *really* need to retrieve the total number of rows before processing them, you can:

1. [ResultSet.last()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#last%28%29)
2. [ResultSet.getRow()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getRow%28%29) to get the total number of rows
3. [ResultSet.beforeFirst()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#beforeFirst%28%29)
4. Process the `ResultSet` normally

Answer (score 3):

As others have answered there is no way to get the count of rows without iterating till the end. You could do that, but you may not want to, note the following points:

1. For a many RDBMS systems ResultSet is a streaming API, this means
   that it does not load (or maybe even fetch) all the rows from the
   database server. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858836/does-a-resultset-load-all-data-into-memory-or-only-when-requested) question on SO. By iterating to the
   end of the ResultSet you may add significantly to the time taken to
   execute in certain cases.
2. A default [ResultSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) object is not updatable and has a cursor
       that moves forward only. I think this means that unless you
   execute
       the query with `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` `rSet.beforeFirst()` will throw
       `SQLException`. The reason it is this way is because there is cost
   with scrollable cursor. According to the documentation, it may throw `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException` even if you create a scrollable cursor.
3. Populating and returning a `List<Operations>` means that you will
       also need extra memory. For very large resultsets this will not
   work
       at all.

So the big question is which RDBMS?. **All in all I would suggest not logging the number of records.**

Answer (score 2):

One better way would be to use `SELECT COUNT` statement of SQL.

Just when you need the count of number of rows returned, execute another query returning the exact number of result of that query.

```
 try
{
   Conn=ConnectionODBC.getConnection();
   Statement stmt = Conn.createStatement();        
    String sqlStmt = sql;        
    String sqlrow = SELECT COUNT(*) from (sql) rowquery;
    String total = stmt.executeQuery(sqlrow);
    int rowcount = total.getInt(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getRow()` method will always yield 0 after a query:

> [ResultSet.getRow()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getRow%28%29)
>
> Retrieves the **current** row number.

Second, you output `totalrec` but never assign anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the number of rows returned in a ResultSet without iterating through it.  And why would you return a ResultSet without iterating through it?  There'd be no point in executing the query in the first place.

A better solution would be to separate persistence from view.  Create a separate Data Access Object that handles all the database queries for you.  Let it get the values to be displayed in the `JTable`, load them into a data structure, and then return it to the UI for display.  The UI will have all the information it needs then.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved that problem. The only I do is:

```
private int num_rows;
```

And then in your method using the resultset put this code

```
while (this.rs.next())
{

    this.num_rows++;
}
```

That's all

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get number of rows from resultset is using **count** function query for database access and then **rs.getInt(1)** method to get number of rows.
from my code look it:

```
    String query = "SELECT COUNT() FROM table";
ResultSet rs = new DatabaseConnection().selectData(query);
rs.getInt(1);
```

this will return int value number of rows fetched from database.
Here DatabaseConnection().selectData() is my code for accessing database.
I was also stuck here but then solved...