# How get the number of rows count by ResultSet in Java

Tags: java, resultset

I want to get the row count of a `ResultSet`.

```
ResultSet rs;
Statement s;
rs=s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable");

//rs.getRowCount; ???
```

Comment: You can also try looking at these similar articles:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886462/get-row-count-of-a-resultset-in-java
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292256/get-number-of-rows-returned-by-resultset-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to the last row of the resultset and get the row number like this:

```
resultSet.last()
int count = resultSet.getRow()
```

But this is inefficient because it has to read all the table data. Better to execute the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable
```

Comment: Huh? `row number` or `number of rows`...

Answer (score 0):

I think we can get count as given below:

```
int size = 0;
try {
    while(rs.next()){
        size++;
    }
}
catch(Exception ex) { }
```

or we can use

```
ResultSet.getRow()
```