# How to get number of rows from a resultResult?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I use the below approach to determine my result set is not empty and proceed to do assertions on the values.

```
...
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select count(*) as rowCount from tbName where...");

while (resultSet.next()) {
   rowCount = Integer.parseInt(resultSet.getString("rowCount"));
}

Assert.assertTrue(rowCount > 0);

resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from tbName where ...");
while (resultSet.next()) {
    //do some assertions on values here.
}
...
```

Is there anyway to get the number of rows directly from the resultSet directly in a single query? Something like the below?

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from tbName where ...");
if( resultSet.count/length/size > 0) {

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Number of Rows returned by ResultSet in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292256/get-number-of-rows-returned-by-resultset-in-java)

Comment: If you *only* want to check if the result is empty, then `next()` will already do that for you: if the first call to `next()` returns false, the result was empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the query to include a column with the row count:

```
select t.*, count(*) over () as row_count
from tbName t
where ...
```

then you can get the count using

```
int rowCount  rs.getInt("row_count");
```

Note that you won't get a `0` count because that means the actual query did not return anything in the first place. So you can't use that to verify if your query returned anything. If you *only* want to check if the result is empty, use `next()`

```
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(".....");
if (resultSet.next()) {
   // at least one row returned
} else {
  // no rows returned at all 
}
```

---

Btw: you should always use the `getXXX()` method that matches the column's data type. Using `getString()` on all columns is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

1) Moves the cursor to the last row: **resultset.last();**

2)Retrieves the current row number: **int count = resultset.getRow();**

Tips:
It's based on you create a statement via calling function "
   Statement createStatement(int resultSetType,int resultSetConcurrency)
                          throws SQLException"
to gernerate a scrollable resultSet.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get number of rows.
1) if you want to check the number of rows exist in table you may use count query.
2) if you want to count number of rows in a result set you have to traverse that result set to count rows.