# Get row count of a ResultSet in java?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I have a problem with ResultSet last() function.
some times it shows the correct data. in some other time it shows another result.

consider i have no data on the table, then it shows row count is 0, but some time it doesn't show any of value.

here my code:

```
if(rs.last()){
int rsCount = rs.getRow();
System.out.println("ResultSet Count is: "+rsCount);
}
```

please give me the solution for my problem.

Comment: what you have in 'rs' object ?

Comment: Why do you want the count at all? Just process the `ResultSet`. Also: please clarify what you mean with _"but some time it doesn't show any of value."_

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292256/get-number-of-rows-returned-by-resultset-in-java?rq=1

Comment: i need count of a row in resultset, if there is no row in a result set, then i want to insert some data into table. so that i am using rs.last() function.

Comment: That still doesn't explain your problem; my guess is you get an `SQLException` that you are swallowing, but you don't provide enough context, nor enough supporting information. As to your use case: why not just select a count, or process the result set and take specific action if no rows were processed, or - if your database supports it - use `MERGE`. Methods like `last()` only work on scrollable result sets which are - usually - not the default.

Comment: ya thanks Sarit Adhikari, now my problem is solved. i am also using the same, that you are suggested. but what is the problem with last() function in ResultSet.

Answer (score -1):

```
rs.last;
int rsCount=rs.getRow();//number of row
```

call `rs.beforeFirst();` and then `while'(rs.next()) {...}` if you want to process every value in the `ResultSet`