# Getting the number of Rows from a MySQL table using Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I've seen a lot of similar questions which try to achieve this by using a while loop to count the entries. But I was hoping that there would be a way similar to this which could work? 
    String SQL = "SELECT Name FROM (table name) TABLE  WHERE                    SCHEMA

```
    PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
    ResultSet a = statement.executeQuery();
    System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: `select count(foo) from bar` + `int numRows = result.getInt(1)` in a separate query would work without much data traffic and without a loop

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Number of Rows returned by ResultSet in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292256/get-number-of-rows-returned-by-resultset-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use count.

```
SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

---

Or you could do it using a variable.

```
int count = 0;
while(rs.next())
  count ++;
```

Comment: he will have to query again to get the data

Answer (score 0):

`ResultSet.last()` followed by `ResultSet.getRow()` will give you the row count, but it may not be a good idea as it can mean reading the entire table over the network and throwing away the data

```
if(rs.last()){
   rowCount = rs.getRow(); 
   rs.beforeFirst();
}
```

via : [How do I get the size of a java.sql.ResultSet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192078/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-a-java-sql-resultset)