# how to run Resultset.next() twice?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, resultset

I have this method to get a string of rows and print them.

Additionally, I have to do `while(Resultset.next())` two times. The first one is to get the number of rows and the second one is to print the string. But when the method runs the first time `Resultset.next()` the method skips the second `Resultset.next()`.

```
public static String[] gett() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

    // this for get conneced to the database .......................

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","hr","111"); 
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet re = st.executeQuery("select location_id from DEPARTMENTS");

    // Ok , now i have the ResultSet ...

    // the num_row it's counter to get number of rows
    int num_row = 0;

    // this Arrar to store String values
    String[] n = new String[num_row];

    // this is the first ResultSet.next , and it's work ..!
    // also , this ResultSet.next work to get number on rows and store the number on 'num_row' 
    while(re.next())
        num_row++;

    // NOW , this is the secound 'ResultSet.next()' , and it's doesn't WORK !!!!
    while(re.next()) {
        System.out.println(re.getString("location_id"));
    }
}
```

The problem is, the first `Resultset.next()` works fine, but the second does not work!

Could someone explain why? And how can I make it work?

note:
I know, there is another way to do it in just one `Resultset.next()`
BUT I want to do it twice ;)

Comment: can't you use one loop and put both the operation in that single loop?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8292500/1799530) answer.

Comment: Why can't you just loop through it once? For the code you show it does not make sense to count this way separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could initialize your `Statement` as the following

```
conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

Due to this you can move the cursor around in the Statement.

Now you could either loop through it.

```
while(re.next())
    num_row++;
re.beforeFirst();
```

but this is quite unneccessary and the optimal solution would be to just jump to the end of the set and return the row

```
num_row = 0;
if(re.last()) {
   num_row = rs.getRow();
   re.beforeFirst();
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Second `rs.next()` is not working because rs already reached into the end position with your first loop.

You can store `re.next()` this into temporary variable.

For example `ResultSet tmpRs_1 = rs;`
`ResultSet tmpRs_2 = rs;`

and then use this two variable for two loop.

Or ,

You can do all the operation within single loop. So that you should not need to two loop.

Comment: You can't do that, because `tmpRs_1` and `tmpRs_2` are still one and the same `ResultSet`.