# How to get the number of records in a mysql database using ResultSet?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to execute following code. Connection is being built successfully.

```
String selectq = "select max(id) as max_id from items";
currentCon = (Connection) ConnectionManager.getConnection();
            stmt=(Statement) currentCon.createStatement();
ResultSet rSelect = stmt.executeQuery(selectq);
```

On executing following command, output is coming as 1 even if there is no row in the table.

```
rSelect.next();
System.out.println(rSelect.getRow());
```

My requirement is to check if there are no records in the table, otherwise I need to get the max of id column from that table.

I have tried many things like

```
rSelect.last();
rSelect.next();
```

But, I am not able to get the required result.

I am using

- Eclipse Indigo 3.7
- JDK 1.6.0_37
- Tomcat 7
- MySQL

Comment: seems to be a duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545820/total-number-of-row-resultset-getrow-method

Comment: I don't consider that a dupe question. Saurabh has an [xy-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). He asked about "x" (how to get total number of records) of which he incorrectly thought that it would solve "y" (how to check if there is no row). The dupe indeed answers "x", but he actually wanted to solve "y", which the dupe doesn't answer at all.

Comment: guys, please check my answer and tell me if i am duping it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after adding a If statement like below:

```
String id = "";


if(rSelect.next()){
    id = rSelect.getString(1);
}
```

Since, there can exists only one row or nothing according to my query.

Comment: Whilst this solves the concrete problem, the approach is clumsy. See the currently top rated answer for a much simpler approach. You don't need a `while(true)` at all. Just a single `if-else` is sufficient. The `else` block indicates "no records" case.

Comment: I have tried using single if-else construct, that doesn't helped me, thats why i am forced to use this clumsy approach.

Comment: Apparently you tried it the wrong way. It works fine for me and everyone else.

Answer (score 3):

You should not be ignoring the outcome of [`ResultSet#next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29). It returns `false` if there's no row. Also, to obtain the first column as an `int`, you should be using [`ResultSet#getInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt%28int%29), passing the column index or column label.

```
if (resultSet.next()) {
    int max = resultSet.getInt("max_id");
} else {
    // There are no records. Set max to -1 or something?
}
```

Comment: +1 ! In my answer I have no thought over case when `resultSet.next()` will return `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `rSelect.getInt(1)` instead of `rSelect.getRow()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use ResultSet like this:

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
  //do something with this row, e.g:
  int id = resultSet.getInt(1);
  //...
}
```

The while loop will iterate through all rows.

Comment: The while loop makes no sense if there can be only 0 or 1 rows. Also, the OP is rather interested in the "there's no rows" case.