# Retrieving the number of entries in a ResultSet

Tags: java, sqlite, resultset

In a few answers here on SO there is recommended to use `ResultSet`'s function `getRow()` in order to get the number of entries in a query result. However, following code

```
private static int getSizeOfResultSet(ResultSet result) throws SQLException{
    if(result != null){
        int count = 0;
        while(result.next()){
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("Count of resultset is " + result.getRow() + " and count " + count);
            return result.getRow();
    }else{
        System.out.println("Result is null");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

is returning me things like

```
Count of resultset is 0 and count 1
```

when there is **assured** that entries are existing (in a JUnit test case). Note that this project has to be in Java6-standard, so maybe this is the issue. Is there anything to consider using the `getRow()` function?

Additionally, I tried with

```
result.last();
int c = result.getRow();
result.beforeFirst();
return c;
```

like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545820/total-number-of-row-resultset-getrow-method), but the result is still 0.

**EDIT**: I should mention that the `while(result.next())`-loop is for testing purpose. The behaviour without the loop is exactly the same (i.e. `0`).

Comment: Why do you need to know how many rows the query returns?  If you must know before you can do anything else, just do a select count (*) from your query.  Or you could just wait until you've put the rows into some sort of collection.

Answer (score 5):

The javadoc states

> **returns** the current row number; 0 if there is no current row

After you've visited all the rows with `ResultSet#next()` there is no current row.

Use your `count` value for the number of rows. Or use a `SELECT count(*) ...` style query.

Comment: as mentioned, even if I only have return `result.getRow()`, it returns 0.

Comment: @ValentinoRu Think about it. If you remove the loop, you are not advancing the cursor and therefore there is no current row.