# know how to get the total row count

Tags: java, database, sqlite, jdbc

i want to get the total row count in the sqlite DB, i referred to some posts and i wrote the below code, but at run time i receive `xception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: SQLite only supports TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY cursors`.

i chnages the parameter to be

```
stmt = conn.createStatement(
            ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, 
            ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

but at run time i receive row count equals 0 despite there are rows in the DB.

kindly please let me know how to get the total row count correctly?

**code**:

```
private final String selectRowCount = "select COUNT(*) from 
"+TABLE_NAME+";";
...
...
public int getRowCount() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Connection conn = getConnection();
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt = conn.createStatement(
            ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, 
            ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    ResultSet resSet = stmt.executeQuery(this.selectRowCount);

    int size = 0;
    try {
        resSet.last();
        size = resSet.getRow();
        resSet.beforeFirst();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        resSet.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "", "RowCount: "+size);
        return 0;
    }

    resSet.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "", "RowCount: "+size);
    return size;
}
```

Comment: try this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545820/total-number-of-row-resultset-getrow-method

Comment: @FastSnail no errors but the number of rows returned is zero

Comment: @AniketDivekar i think it is the same as i did, any suggestions please?

Comment: Just try with zero parameters in createStatement or other types of cursor parameters

Comment: @sunrise76 can u please show an example how to get rowcount using ResSetMetaData? i created a small test but that class can provide info about the columns in the table?

Comment: Sorry for my earlier comment. It does not have required API. Try with other types of cursors.

Comment: @sunrise76 i did but still reciving the same erro message posted above in the post

Comment: Can you check http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0292.html

Comment: @sunrise76 i have checked that link u posted as well. the 2ndcode snippet gives the same error. the 1st one, works, but i am concerned about the cursor position, because after "s.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowcount FROM MyTable");" there is "r.next();" andi dont know how to set the cursor back to the initial positon

Comment: @sunrise76 and the 1st code in the link u posted, works without calling r.next()? and explanation please?

Comment: The query itself will return row count. next is not required since one row is returned