# Java how to retrieve more than 1 million rows in a Resultset

Tags: java, jdbc

I am executing select query on a table of MYSQL which has 16,213,156 rows and 10 columns. But after connection is established code just executes for few mins and then throws error : **Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**

My system configuration is 16 gb RAM, Java 8

I tried setting Jvm Parameters as -Xms4G & -Xmx12G . Also tried setting stmt.setFetchSize();  // to 10,100,1000 still same error

Can we fetch such large number of records using JDBC API am I missing anything ? Any help would be really appreciated.

```
package com;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Date;

import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;

public class Test1 {
    private static Connection conn = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException {

        connection();
        retrieve(conn);

    }



    public static void connection()
    {

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String url = "<jdbc connection url>";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "<username>", "<password>");
            System.out.println("Connection established");       
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public static void retrieve(Connection conn)
    {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try
        {

            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            //  stmt.setFetchSize(100); // 1000, 10
            System.out.println(stmt.getFetchSize());  // By default prints 0
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tablename");
            CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\finaldata\\test.csv")));
            System.out.println("**** Started writing Data to CSV ****");
            int lines = writer.writeAll(rs, true, false, false);        
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            System.out.println("** OpenCSV -Completed writing the resultSet at " +  new Date() + " Number of lines written to the file " + lines);  

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why to retrieve more than 1 million rows in a Resultset ?

Comment: Why not paginate? Grab records 0-20, 21-40, 41-60, etc...

Comment: @JacekCz  is there any other way for records around 50 lac this code works. Issue is only for this 1 table so wanted to use same approach of resultset. If there is any other approach then can you please point me to a helpful example

Comment: Have you checked with profiler what consumes memory? With ResultSet it is possible to extract hundreds of million of records if you process them one by one

Comment: I agree with @Ivan, you are going to have to memory-profile this.  There's nothing obviously wrong with the code.  Internally, `writeAll()` applied to a `ResultSet` iterates over the rows one at a time.

Comment: What do you mean set one row at a time, what about the sql queries. As the call is synchronous all the records get returned by database server at once. How will you say that those will not loaded into memory. Can you prove it?

Comment: Which opencsv lib are you using?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn OpenCSV4.0

Comment: @GauravSrivastav please check answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858836/does-a-resultset-load-all-data-into-memory-or-only-when-requested

Comment: @Ivan, Jim Thanks but unfortunately Memory Analyzer fails while parsing .hprof file. Can you please identify what must be causing this memory issue.

Comment: Setting fetch size alone might not be enough for the MySQL driver to start streaming the data from the DB instead of loading everything at once. You could try with `stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY); stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);` (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/859032/905488)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@MickMnemonic Thanks for your help this solved the issue.

Setting **fetchSize** alone might not be enough for the MySQL driver to start streaming the data from the DB instead of loading everything at once. You could try with

```
stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, 
ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY); stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Limit the query, like,

```
SELECT * FROM message_history limit {start from row no.} , {no. of rows to select}
```

example-

```
SELECT * FROM message_history limit 100000,200000;
```

will retrieve rows from 100000 to 300000;
like this divide into batches.also

```
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(query);
statement.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
rs = statement.executeQuery();
```

This method worked for me to retrieve 22 million records.

Comment: Good Idea, but I see slight discrepancy in you statements. SELECT * FROM message_history limit 100000,200000; will not retrieve 100000 to 200000 records, it fetches 200000 records from 100000.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to some searching or manipulation try to do at database Layer rather to fetch all of them in Application Layer and then do manipulation/searching. Getting the large set of records is not good practice. Provide the search filter option there so that user can filter the records as per their need, as records grow this really tedious task for you to manage all these.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question and is more of a comment.  Also, under the covers `writeAll()` applied to a `ResultSet` iterates over the result set one row at a time and does not load all records into memory.  Something else is happening.

Comment: What do you mean set one row at a time, what about the sql queries. As the call is synchronous all the records get returned by database server at once. How will you say that those will not loaded into memory. Can you prove it?

Answer (score -1):

I've run into a similar problem reading some million rows from a MySQL DB. 
I'm reading with a PreparedStatement called reader. Then just after the  PrepareStatement I've reduced the fetchsize to minimum:

```
PreparedStatement reader = connection.prepareStatement("select....");
reader.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

and from then on, I've never run into problems.

Comment: -1; See Javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize(int). No effect for negative values