# Resultset.next() is not moving ahead after fetching 2.14B records out of 2.5B records and exists out after long time

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm fetching records from Oracle 12c using JDBC driver. I have total 2.5B records. After successfully fetching 2.14B records (2147483000), `rs.next()` got stuck and is not moving ahead and times out after a long time. I'm fetching this data from a simple hash partitioned table with 2000+ child partitions having a single NUMBER data typed column. Also, I do have sufficient memory on my machine.

Suggestions/ideas anyone?

Comment: To rule out possible problems limited to your Oracle instance itself, can you do a select * on this table from Oracle developer without the system crashing?

Comment: That number is suspiciously close to the max value of an `int` (2,147,483,647). Perhaps the implementation is overflowing.

Comment: @Slaw, right I was suspecting the same, but not getting where to look further

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java how to retrieve more than 1 million rows in a Resultset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50953347/java-how-to-retrieve-more-than-1-million-rows-in-a-resultset)

Comment: Do you have to process all 2.5 billion records with a single query?

Answer (score 2):

Here I found the answer,

I was using ojdbc7 driver and resultset has a limitation of fetching records count of Integer.MAX_VALUE i.e. 2147483647

After updating ***ojdbc7 to ojdbc8***, the issue got resolved and it successfully fetched the rest of the records.

Comment: Please be aware that ojdbc7 vs ojdbc8 is not a version of the driver, the 7 and 8 just specify the targeted Java version. It would be very helpful to include the exact versions of the old and the new driver.