# How to avoid out of memory when constructing a map of more than 100 thousand keys

Tags: java, dictionary, out-of-memory

I am working on a code in java where I am going through a database table and constructing the list of unique items from that table with a key which is a string value (item name and could be upto 1024 characters long) and a number (long). The table can contain 100K or more unique items. The code is something like that:

```
Map<String, long> getUniqueItems() {  
   Map<Stirng, long> map = new HashMap<>();  
   recordsItr = readDatabaseRecord();  
   while(recordItr.hasNext()) {  
       RecordItem item = recordItr.next();  
       map.put(item.getName(), item.getValue();  
   }  

   return map; 
}
```

However, if the number of unique records is huge then ofcourse I will get out of memory in the application. How can I avoid getting out or memory while constructing this. At the end, once i get the map i use it to iterate through its entries and do something with each item.

Thanks,

Arsalan

Comment: Generally speaking, don't slurp the whole thing into memory; iterate over the database `ResultSet` (or equivalent).

Comment: Also generally speaking: 100k items should not be so much of a problem, unless the entries are *huge* in some way. More info is probably needed here.

Comment: you can use the `setFetchSize()` method on the ResultSet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858836/does-a-resultset-load-all-data-into-memory-or-only-when-requested

Comment: are you running 64-bit or 32-bit vm?

Answer (score 0):

As @Marco13's comment, 100k elements is not too huge to storage in main memory. But, If `recordsItr` is a array, the compiler will require **consecutive** pieces of memory to storage the elements, in this case you can get out of memory problem if your main memory is cramped. Instead of using array, you can you another data structure that **does not require consecutive memory**, ther are `stack`, `queue`, `linked list`,...I think they are enough for the 100k elements( if more, I am not sure). Further, don't forget to optimize your code to reduce using too much memory.