# Apache POI word table giving OOM exception on large set of data

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi

I am using apache poi to generate Word from jdbc query . It works fine for 4000 records but once we inserted 17000 records in the table, I started getting Java Out of Memory space . I am getting all the data in one shot as shown below , is there a way to insert rows in word table in batches or any other optimized way which I am missing.

This is my driver code which gets in table name and HttpServlet and passes it to class which implements ResultSetExtractor.

```
public void generateWord(String tableName, HttpServletResponse response, String[] filter) throws DataAccessException, IOException {
        //Table validation logic
        String sql = "select * from table";
        mainJdbcTemplate.query(sql, paramMap,
                new StreamingWordResultSetExtractor(response.getOutputStream(), tableName));
    }
```

Custom class which implements Result Set extractor . I get in all the result set data and use poi to generate Word.

```
public class StreamingWordResultSetExtractor implements ResultSetExtractor<Void> {

    private final OutputStream os;
    private String tableName;

    /**
     * @param os the OutputStream to stream the Excel to
     */
    public StreamingWordResultSetExtractor(final OutputStream os, final String tableName) {
        this.os = os;
        this.tableName = tableName;
    }

    // Set Custom Font Size
    static void setFontSize(XWPFTableCell cell, int size) {
        for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : cell.getParagraphs()) {
            for (XWPFRun run : paragraph.getRuns()) {
                run.setFontSize(size);
            }
        }
    }

    // Set table cell as link
    static void setLink(XWPFTableCell cell, String text, String link) {
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = cell.addParagraph();
        XWPFRun run = paragraph.createHyperlinkRun(link);
        run.setText(text);
        run.setUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.SINGLE);
        run.setColor("0000FF");

    }

    // Set table style
    static XWPFStyle createTableStyle(XWPFStyles styles, String styleId) {
        //omitting code
        return style;
    }

    @Override
    public Void extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();

        log.info("Generating Word");
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

        // Set page orientation
        CTDocument1 ctDocument = document.getDocument();
        CTBody ctBody = ctDocument.getBody();
        CTSectPr ctSectPr = (ctBody.isSetSectPr()) ? ctBody.getSectPr() : ctBody.addNewSectPr();
        CTPageSz ctPageSz = (ctSectPr.isSetPgSz()) ? ctSectPr.getPgSz() : ctSectPr.addNewPgSz();
        ctPageSz.setOrient(STPageOrientation.LANDSCAPE);

        // set paper size A3
        ctPageSz.setW(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(Math.round(23.4 * 1440))); // 16.5 inches
        ctPageSz.setH(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(Math.round(16.5 * 1440))); // 11.7 inches

        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
        run.setText(tableName);

        // Creating Table with 1 row and as many columns as in the result set
        XWPFTable table = document.createTable(1, columnsNumber);

        // Get header Row
        XWPFTableRow header = table.getRow(0);
        // Set header columns
        for (int col = 0; col < columnsNumber; col++) {
            header.getCell(col).setText(rsmd.getColumnLabel(col + 1));
            // header.getCell(col).getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewShd().setFill("0394fc");
            setFontSize(header.getCell(col), 8);

        }
        // Repeat header on every page
        header.setRepeatHeader(true);
        // Set data rows
        while (rs.next()) {
            XWPFTableRow desRow = table.createRow();
            for (int col = 0; col < columnsNumber; col++) {
                final var value = rs.getObject(col + 1);
                String v = value == null ? "" : value.toString();

                if (v.startsWith("<a")) {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(v);
                    Elements rows = doc.getElementsByTag("a");
                    String text = "";
                    for (Element element : rows) {
                        text = element.text();
                        String href = element.attr("href").trim();
                        String encURL = "";
                        encURL = UriUtils.encodePath(href, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                        setLink(desRow.getCell(col), text, encURL);
                        setFontSize(desRow.getCell(col), 7);
                    }

                } else {
                    desRow.getCell(col).setText(v);
                    setFontSize(desRow.getCell(col), 7);
                }
            }
        }

        table.removeBorders();
        XWPFStyles styles = document.createStyles();
        XWPFStyle style;
        style = createTableStyle(styles, "ListTableStyle");
        table.setStyleID(style.getStyleId());
        try {
            document.write(os);
            document.close();
            log.info("Word generation complete");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Error occurred: {0}", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: In a cell refer to a style, instead of individually set attributes like color.

Comment: word docx is not a good format for large data sets - could you consider HTML or some other format better suited to streaming?

Comment: @PJFanning the requirement is to export table data in pdf , excel and docx. The other 2 file type (pdf , excel) are working smoothly but docx is giving issue.

Comment: "The other ... file type (..., excel) are working smoothly": I doubt Excel (`*.xlsx`) will work "smoothly" for any size of data. Excel (`*.xlsx`) as well as Word (`*.docx`) are Office Open XML file formats. This are ZIP archives containing XML files and other files in a special directory structure. These files reference to each other and the references are stored in `*.ref` files in that ZIP directory structure. So for each data entry several files in that ZIP directory structure needs to be changed. This is not something that data can be streamed in.

Comment: @AxelRichter It works fine on excel . Here is the code snippet for Excel generation: https://codeshare.io/OdzBlA 
Is the docx failing because there are excessive styling added.

Comment: As said, there are structural problems with streaming data into Office Open XML files because of the internal file structure. So "It works fine on excel." means: It works until now, up to current used data size. And to your additional question: What happens if you omit the styling?

Comment: I didn't try omitting styling because it is one of the requirements.

Comment: @AxelRichter Is there a way to load  data in batch , flush it and then load data from another batch in XWPFTable . Any other utlity apart from poi which can support this requirement?

Comment: The requirements are nonsense. A Word document containing a table having 17,000 data rows is nothing what I would expect as a end-user. What shall I do with that? Reading hundreds of pages with table rows? Neither PDF nor Word nor Excel are really good formats for data exchange because of not really good able for machine reading. If the aim is data exchange then there are much better formats as CSV, XML, JSON, ...

Comment: If the aim is to inform a end-user, then the result should not contain that big amount of data. The program should ask the end-user what he really needs and filter the data before exporting.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that `ResultSet rs` fetches the data lazily (depending on your configuration the whole query will be in memory and/or will not be freed when doing `rs.next`). Read more about this jdbc [behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/858863/1540749).

With this, you can be sure that your jdbc query consumes very little memory.

On the other hand, the [XWPFDocument](https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/trunk/poi-ooxml/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.java) class store all intermediate data in memory:

```
public class XWPFDocument extends POIXMLDocument implements Document, IBody {
    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(XWPFDocument.class);

    protected List<XWPFFooter> footers = new ArrayList<>();
    protected List<XWPFHeader> headers = new ArrayList<>();
    protected List<XWPFHyperlink> hyperlinks = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
```

then, you **cannot use that class** to generate your file in a streaming fashion way.

Now your processing limit is the memory used by this class.

If it consumes a lot of memory (which is likely), a dirty way is generate multiple output files and join these using some other utility or (since they are xml) join ciertain xml elements directly.

If you can generate an spreadsheet instead doc, you can use the streaming version [SXSSFSheet](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFSheet.html).

Comment: I tried setting the fetchSize , still issue persists . I am using SQL Server 2019 btw.

Comment: @Laduanand the memory consumption could be from jdbc but sure from `XWPFDocument` class, you can use `jmeter` or similar to confirm this but it's clear for me.

Comment: its from XWPFDocument class

Comment: Can you point me to some article or code for "a dirty way is generate multiple output files and join these using some other utility or (since they are xml) join ciertain xml elements directly"

Comment: @Laduanand if you can generate an spreadsheet instead a doc file you can use the streaming version SXSSFSheet.